# Upload file on the server through REST API

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm trying to upload file on server through REST API. My api requests FormData model, but Im getting `400 bad request` error.

**payload from my request in devtools**

------WebKitFormBoundaryvPiRGxMC3Ru3AoFA
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"; filename="test.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg

------WebKitFormBoundaryvPiRGxMC3Ru3AoFA--

**payload from my docs**

file: (binary)

Just look some code below.

upload.component.html

`<input type="file" accept="image/*" (change)="onFileChange($event)">`

upload.component.ts

```
uploadForm = this._fb.group({
    profile: ['']
});
formData: FormData = new FormData();
...
onFileChange(event): void {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files.length) {
        const file = event.target.files[0];
        this.uploadForm.get('profile').setValue(file);
    };
}
...
upload() {
    this.formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('profile').value);
    // API REQUEST
}
```

`

Is that the good way to change my input value to `FormData`?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: `400 bad request` https://pasteboard.co/IqdTuZ0.png its payload from my request and its payload from my docs https://pasteboard.co/IqdU0a0.png

Comment: All this information should be present in your question. Avoid external links if possible.

Comment: Sure, my bad. Edited.

Comment: formdata should be appended with multipart/form-data.                                               
formData.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data');

Comment: Problem solved. Http header `Content-Type` was hardcoded to `application/json`. But it should depends on request type. Thank you @Ramachandran your hint was important there.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please change your code from

```
this.formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('profile'.value);
```

to

```
this.formData.append('file', this.uploadForm.get('profile').value);
```

Comment: Typo in question, sorry. Locally i got `('profile').value`